# Does this amount to valid class instantiation?

Tags: php, class, instance

Came across this code while learning PHP:

```
return (new $controller)->$action()
```

and couldnt get what is going on. From the basics I know, you can't call a method with a $ sign and I never know you can instantiate an object as a variable as in the code above. Thanks.

Comment: *"From the basics I know, you can't call a method with a $ sign and I never know you can instantiate an object as a variable as in the code above."* -- just because you didn't know about them it doesn't mean they cannot be done this way. You just learned that these things are, in fact, possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) (similar concept is [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

In your case it means the following:

`$controller` and `$action` are **variables** and have some values.
For example

```
$controller = 'HomeController';
$action = 'index';
```

So, replacing `$controller` and `$action` with their values you get:

```
return (new HomeController)->index()
```

Which now means: create instance of `HomeController` class and execute `index` method of this created instance. Data received from `index` method will be returned.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: I'd say the are [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) rather than variable variables.

Comment: To clarify: This is not a `variable variable`. It's a normal variable which holds a method name, and you can simply call a method that way. `variable variable` is a variable that holds a name of another variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications plus immediate response. Can't thank you enough honestly.